# (gnuradio) Is there a way I can use "python block" to make a source?

Tags: python, gnuradio, adc

I have an ADC module with 1 MHZ sampling rate.
Here is the URL of his [sample program](https://designspark-pmod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic-examples.html#print-volts-out-to-the-terminal)

I will give him a 40khz carrier signal as an analog input. I want to write the voltage signal he received into the "python block" of "GNURADIO". let his

```
output_items[0][:]=adc.readA1Volts()
```

But when I do this it runs out:

```
swig director method error: error detected when calling 'feval_p.eval'
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

(I'm not very good in English, I translated it by Google, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, yes. You can write a GNU Radio source in Python.

> `output_items[0][:]=adc.readA1Volts()`

That says "assign the many items in `output_items[0]` the value or values from `adc.readA1Volts()`, which is almost certainly not correct.

Possibly, something throws an error here, maybe because of array size mismatch or similar, and hence that error you see arises.

I think this reflects a bit of misunderstanding on how to write a python block. The [Official GNU Radio Tutorials](https://tutorials.gnuradio.org) might be the best place to start.

Answer (score 0):

adc.readA1Volts() is a single voltage (POINT) that will read adc, I can store it as a matrix,

ex:

```
ADC=[]
ADC.append(adc.readA1Volts())
```

Then it is output by output_items[0],
ex:

```
output_items[0][:]=ADC
```

Is this thought correct?
I don't know what his output form is like.